# What if a referee doesn't respond on time?

Tags: application, reference-request

Imagine the scenario where someone applies for an academic position, for a postdoc or later career stage. Three letters of reference are needed by the closing date on the application; two letters arrive on time but one doesn't. What's likely to happen? Does this mean the application would be disqualified? Would the institute be likely to allow more time for the referee to respond or for the candidate to find a new referee?

I imagine how this would be dealt with would vary between institutes, research groups etc., so I'd be interested to know if anyone has a similar experience to this either as the employer or candidate, or if people are aware of universities with policies that restrict what the research group listing the position is allowed to do (eg. there could be a university policy that says 'no late references accepted')

Comment: What kind of position? There are some related questions, e.g. [Is it generally acceptable if reference letters for postdoc or faculty jobs are submitted after the application deadline?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/5767/17254), [Can late recommendation letters have a negative impact on grad school application?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/99771/17254), [Late letter of recommendation for grad schools](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101269/17254)

Comment: There are too many variations and options to have any general answer here beyond "it depends". I could give my opinion about how it should work, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm asking about a postdoc job listing or later career stage

Comment: The norms for this vary depending on the country the job it is in and the field, and individual jobs will also differ from the norm.

Comment: A single data point: I was offered what would now be called a postdoc position (in those days it was a research instructorship) even though only two of my three referees had sent their letters.